# Standard visit visa for training purpose for the UK

Tags: united-kingdom

I am preparing to travel to the UK and get training for a startup, learning about programming and project management. My training is 7 months long and is sponsored by the company.

As I need a visa for the UK, and the standard visa gives you permission to get get training and stay for longer then 6 months, I wanted to know how I can apply for it. What are the conditions and what documents will I need from the company that is providing thee training?

Some questions:

- Will I be allowed to attend a sponsored training by a UK company?
- What documents will I need from the company to apply for the visa?
- As the company will be sponsoring me, do I have to show my own personal savings details to show I have enough funds to stay in the UK?
- What's the procedure to apply for the visa?

Comment: The standard visitor visa does not generally allow stays of longer than six months, and training is not among the exceptions discussed on the information page.  https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Comment: You're going to have real trouble convincing the authorities that 7 months of training does not count as either a course of study (requiring a student visa) or work (requiring a work visa).